# When do we have $D_{\text{perf}}(\text{Qcoh}(X))\simeq D_{\text{perf}}(X)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a scheme (or more generally a ringed space). We know that in general the derived category of complexes of quasi-coherent modules $D(\text{Qcoh}(X))$ is not equivalent to the derived category of complexes of arbitrary $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $D(X)$.

Nevertheless Thomason&Trobaugh's  "Higher algebraic k-theory of schemes and of derived categories" B.16 and moreover SGA 6 tells us (if I understand it correctly) that

Let $X$ be either quasi-compact
and semi-separated scheme, or else noetherian scheme. Then the natural functor
$$
\phi: D_{+}(\text{Qcoh}(X))\rightarrow D_{+}(X)
$$
is an equivalence, where $D_{+}(\bullet)$ is the derived category of complexes with  bounded below cohomologies.

Now we turn to perfect complexes. For definition of perfect complex see this MO question [How to prove that any perfect complex on an affine scheme is strictly perfect?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199516/how-to-prove-that-any-perfect-complex-on-an-affine-scheme-is-strictly-perfect)

Let us denote $D_{\text{perf}}(\text{Qcoh}(X))$ the derived category of perfect complexes of quasi-coherent modules and $D_{\text{perf}}(X)$ the derived category of perfect complexes of any $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

By the above result in Thomason&Trobaugh, if $X$ is a quasi-compact and semi-separated scheme, or a noetherian scheme, then we have
$D_{\text{perf}}(\text{Qcoh}(X))\simeq D_{\text{perf}}(X)$.

$\textbf{My question}$ is: do we have a weaker condition on $X$ which still guarantees that $D_{\text{perf}}(\text{Qcoh}(X))\simeq D_{\text{perf}}(X)$?

Comment: The functor you write is not an equivalence, but is rather fully faithful with essential image spanned by the complexes with quasi-coherent cohomology.  That said, your claim is still true.  I doubt that the assumptions can be relaxed, though.  Verdier's counterexample in SGA 6 shows that this is unreasonable without something stronger than quasi-separated.  While without quasi-compactness, it is not even true that perfect complexes are cohomologically bounded.  What kind of generality were you hoping for?

Comment: @Adeel Yes, that's obviously my mistake. After reading your comment now I believe that maybe quasi-compact and quasi-separated is the best I can expect.